Icons not displaying correctly for certain Windows version in VB 6 application
So I have a VB 6 application. I am using ImageList and Image controls to add and display icons in my application.
But for some reason they are displaying incorrectly for certain windows version(s).
When I am running the application in the VM which has Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, the icons seem to look perfect.
However, If I test this in my development VM which has Windows Server 2019 Standard, the icons seem to have a black outline appearing.
I have also attached the screenshots highlighting icons (in red squares) having sort of black outline in Windows Server 2019 and looking good in Windows Server 2008 R2.
For win 2008


For win 2019


ImageList control


I have tried changing the base width of the images from the properties in the designer, as it does seem something to do with the width.
I have implemented resizing in the application so even in the Windows Server 2019, it starts to look at a certain size of the window
What can be the issue? The icons are of type .ico (32x32).
Any sort of directions would be appreciated!

First: if it's a VB6 application, the tag Winforms doesn't apply. As for the issue: try creating a *.ico file that includes multiple sized icons (16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64).

My first reaction is that this is caused by the Windows Display Settings, the Scale value could be different than 100%. I would also try the different Compatibility modes for that application.

It's not okay to still be using Server 2008 R2. It's been formally end-of-life for several years now, meaning it no longer gets any updates... not even critical security patches. That's a BIG DEAL. It's the kind of a thing where lawyers on the other side of the table might use words like "gross negligence". I understand you may not have direct control here, but it's your job to surface this issue with those who do... over and over again, if needed.

Cross posted here.

VB6 Image control can handle GIFs with transparent background. If you have access to the original images, you can process them with some image processing app like GIMP and see what happens at runtime.

If I remember correctly, VB6 accepts icons up to 24 bits. I usually use the Greenfish Icon Editor to create an icon with multiple layers of different sizes and bits.
I personally use 16x16, 32x32, and 48x48 and 8, 16, 24 and 32 bits.
